# Transition color with background color

Tags: jquery, css

I have a website with blue background, from top to bottom.  Now I would like to, through css make the blue go from lightest blue at the top to the darkest blue at the bottom.  So basically the page transitions to darker as you scroll down.  Is this possible with css or even jquery?  I was not able to find a solution anywhere, all the examples I have found were when you hover over and it transitions as an effect, but what I am trying to achieve is with background that happens as the page loads.  is this possible with either css or jQuery?

Comment: Google CSS gradients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using CSS gradients

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

---

Yeah just apply the background gradient to which ever thing you want to style like below.

As you can see if you're supporting all the browsers it can get quite messy, so personally I would recommend doing it with LESS, but the below should be fine

```
body{ background: #162772; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #162772 0%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#162772), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #162772 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #162772 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #162772 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #162772 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#162772', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */  }
```

Comment: Just don't link to a page with the answer try to make an example to complement it :) or make this as a comment

Comment: how does that work?  Where do I put the generated code, in a css file?

Comment: Yea I edited original answer

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not supported by each browser yet, I like to use the following gradient method so you only have to edit it on one place; background-color

```
background-color:blue;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
```